# Detailed examples of what Keras cannot do but Pytorch can?

Tags: keras, pytorch, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I read many articles saying Keras is too high level and hard to be used for research. I found Keras has Lambda layer, and custom layer, so what are some detailed examples of what Pytorch can achieve while Keras cannot or is very tricky to? Thanks.

Comment: What you read are just opinions, SO isn't really the place for such kind of discussion.

Comment: Lack of reproducibility, try setting seed in Keras, than try `torch.manual_seed()`. But I agree, too broad of a topic